# laravel-dompdf: How do I make dompdf render a pdf of the same page that it is called from?

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

What I'm trying to do is pass a page to dompdf in order to render it, but the button to render the page is located on the page itself.

The Page (index.blade.php)

```
<div class="event-links">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- <a href="{{    URL::to('/events/create')   }}"> -->
            <a href="{{ action('StrawdogController@pdfgen')}}">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Generate PDF</div>
            </a>                
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nametag-layout">
        <table class="table table-striped pagin-table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mod Start Time</td>
                    <td>Mod End Time</td>
                    <td>Mod Description</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($mods as $key => $value)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_start_time }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_end_time }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and the Controller function (placeholder)

```
public function pdfgen()
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadView('strawdogs.index');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
}
```

}

There is a button on my page called 'Generate PDF' and I want the user to be able to press it and get a PDF of the table which is located on the same page. At the moment, I've tried and I can see it passes along values if you call to another page, but it doesn't seem to do it for the same page.

Basically, is there a way to call dompdf on the same page, and if so, how do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new view(pdf.blade.php) without the render button.
When the the render button on index.blade.php is clicked, generate the pdf from the pdf.blade.php.

PDF Page (pdf.blade.php)

```
<div class="nametag-layout">
    <table class="table table-striped pagin-table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Mod Start Time</td>
                <td>Mod End Time</td>
                <td>Mod Description</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($mods as $key => $value)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $value->mod_description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->mod_start_time }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->mod_end_time }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the Controller function (placeholder)

```
public function pdfgen()
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadView('strawdogs.pdf');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your controller you have to call view method and send variables with compact  and then use loadHtml() and pass the view method as a parameter.

```
        $options = new Options();
        $options->set('defaultFont', 'DejaVu Sans');
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
        // instantiate and use the dompdf class
        $html = view('pages.callsheet_view', compact(['request'],['number_of_no']));
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html,'UTF-8');


        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PDF::loadView('x.blade.php')->output();
```